# Angular 2/NPM: create directory with all the files I need to run the app

Tags: angular, npm

This is a frustration post, but figured it was worth a try.
We're trying to do a typescript angular 2 hello world app which we'd like to distribute as the front end for a spring app.

So far it's based off the angular 2 quickstart here:  https://angular.io/guide/quickstart

The app works great with npm start.

But what I would like is a directory or zip or something that I can use to take that same app and statically deploy it (in my case, shove it into a war with maven).

I've been trying to slurp up all the files from the root directory and dist (which it seems like it wants to actually be named /app) and node_modules and it still seems like it's missing some files.

Is there a simple npm command or some examples to show how to get to the static files?

It feels like I'm doing a whole lot of configuration and not very much convention for something pretty standard.

Comment: If you're new to JS development try using the Angular CLI, then you can just `ng build` to create an `index.html` and a handful of JavaScript. This can be deployed easily to anything with a web server.

Comment: Thx.  I'll check that out.  Is that seen as an alternative to npm?

Comment: I use angular-cli and it makes making a ng2 app so easy! I would highly recommend it. Check out the `ng build` https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#creating-a-build

Comment: It's not an alternative, it *uses* NPM.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the [angular-cli](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-cli) tool to generate a seed site instead, you get the [`ng build` command](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#creating-a-build) to build the site.

That command will generate a folder named `dist`. That folder contains the complete site that can then be statically deployed somewhere else.